# Problemas com encoding no java

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, jdbc

Estou com um problema classico de encoding, fiz varios testes, porem nada resolveu. O problema ocorre apenas com dados trazidos da base de dados em Sql Server, com o texto fixo na tela ta funcionando perfeitamente.

tentei:

> acrescentar na jsp: <%@page contentType="text/html"pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
>
> usar o collate "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" no select do sqlserver
>
> acrescentar "CharacterSet=UTF-8" na string de conexão jdbc

e outras, mas não consegui resolver o problema, segue a baixo um registro da tabela para servir como exemplo:

"EstÃƒÂ¡ ocorrendo uma falha no cadastro WS"

alguem sabe me o q posso fazer pra resolver isso?

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar a origem do problema no seu código na pergunta.

Comment: como assim a origem do problema? os dados estão gravados no sistema dessa forma "EstÃƒÂ¡ ocorrendo uma falha no cadastro WS" preciso exibilos normalmente, com esse "EstÃƒÂ¡" tem que ser exibido como "está", é isso q vc quis dizer?

Comment: @user3061516 Pelo que entendi do registro da tabela que você forneceu, os dados estão gravados errados no banco de dados. É isso mesmo? Se for isso, tudo o que você fez não vai corrigir o problema, afinal seria na entrada e não na saída.

Comment: cara, isso é problema de "charset" em php se eu fizer um " header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); " resolve, quero saber como resolvr isso em java.

Comment: O problema é que algumas versões do SQL Server não tem suporte a UTF-8 nativamente, como pode ser visto nessa página: https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/232580/description-of-storing-utf-8-data-in-sql-server Mas existem formas de superar esse incoveniente, mesmo que perdendo algumas funcionalidades, como é explicado nos passos 4 e 5.